# Error in signing Jar file programmatically with JDK1.6 but working with JDK1.7

Tags: java, android, java-6, jarsigner

We are developing a Java Utility to sign the Jar file programmatically but are facing issues is Signing Jar for JDK 1.6 where as it is working properly for JDK1.7

Below given is the code snippet used for signing the APK file :

```
private void signAPK(){

    APK_SIGNER_COMMAND = "jarsigner -verbose -keystore keystore_file.keystore -digestalg SHA1 apk_file.apk Alias_Value -storepass Password_value";

    try {
        System.out.println(APK_SIGNER_COMMAND);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(APK_SIGNER_COMMAND);

        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));            
        String line=reader.readLine();              
        while(line!=null){ 
            System.out.println(line);
            line=reader.readLine();
        }       

        reader.close();
        p.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For JDK1.7 jar / apk file is getting signed properly, but for JDK 1.6 application is blocked at line where reader readsline (String line=reader.readLine();).
Can someone help why this might not be working for JDK1.6 version.

Thanks. Help Appreciated.

Comment: Does any one have the answer for this query ? Need Help for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using the SHA1, For JDK1.6 use SHA256. you might be able to sign it.

Changing the digest algorithm might help.

Jarsigner uses different digest algorithms for JDK1.7 and JDK1.6

[JDK1.6 jarsigner docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html#DefaultAlgs)

[JDK1.7 jarsigner docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html#DefaultAlgs)